# Ruby Nokogiri HTML scraping table with CSS issue

Tags: html, css, ruby, web-scraping, nokogiri

I have an issue with the scraping of an html-table. 
Here is the link : 
https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/c/curryst01/gamelog/2016
(yes, it's a famous introductive tutorial for Ruby-scraping). 
Here is the code related :

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(open(link))

# Get the biggest table 
big_table = doc.css("table").sort { |x,y| y.css("tr").count <=> x.css("tr").count }.first

# Number of rows is 87, but there are 5 heads that I wanna remove   
big_table.css("tr").count

# This doesn't remove heads 
big_table = big_table.select { |row| row.css("th").empty? }
```

In fact in HTML (I know nothing about HTML and i am in Ruby since 4h) th is the tag for header, td is for a standard cell, and tr is just a line. 
The goal was to delete the header, so as the `.empty` return if a nodeset (nodeset is like the content of a tag ? ) is empty, this last line of code should have return only the tr elements. 
But it doesn't work, in fact the result is [] .
Instead, I noticed that : 
`big_table.select{|row| row.css("td").empty?}.count` was equal to 5 ... 
So, i decided to do :

`big_table = big_table.select{|row| row.css("td").any?}` and it worked well...

My question is : why did this line works ? and why the first attempt did fail ? 
Maybe it's something in the HTML structure that i'm missing ...

Thanks !

Comment: I'm not clear: what are you looking to extract from the page?

Comment: I'm trying to extract the data from the first table. Here is the tutorial video that i'm following https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1UYBAn69Qrk&t=560s (start at 9min20 until 11min20). I copied exactly what this guy did, and as i mentioned the " row.css(td) empty?" line did not do the job. Thanks !

Comment: Unrelated to your question, while looking for the largest table is interesting (I'd use `max_by` rather than `sort`), you really only need to find the appropriate ID since IDs are unique, i.e. `big_table=doc.css("#pgl_basic")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take a look at `big_table`

```
> big_table.class
 => Nokogiri::XML::NodeSet

> big_table.size
 => 1
```

So first of all, doing `Enumerable#select` against `big_table` is probably not doing what you expect. If instead you capture the rows:

```
> rows = big_table.css("tr")
> rows.count
 => 87
```

Now you can do your `select` on the rows. Let's take an arbitrary row and see what it contains:

```
> rows[2].css("td").count
 => 29

> rows[2].css("th").count
 => 1
```

So a typical row has 29 `td` elements and one `th`. In fact every row has at least one `th`, which is why the `css("th").empty?` returned nothing. Conversely, the all-header rows do not contain any `td` elements, which is why what you tried worked.

Comment: Huge thanks for your explanations ! :) It's much clearer now. By the way, do you know a course .pdf to begin with ruby, nokogiri languages (i'm really starting in both languages) ? thanks again ! :)